# Entity Framework 4.1 Code First mapping/populating a single property from two db columns

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.1

I know this question has been asked/answered but I can't find it for the life of me.

I am creating and ASP.NET MVC 3 app with an existing db but wanted to go code first so I'm used the EF Power Tools CTP1 to get me started.  Ultimately, I will refactor to a better solution but to get going I used the `MVCScaffolding` to gen up controllers and views.  I'm struggling with creating a display value (`FullName`) property on my model that is a combination of the `FirstName` and `LastName` columns in the DB.

I have a simple class

```
public class Manager
{
    public Manager(){}

    public int ManagerID { get; set; }

    [DisplayName] // Not in db.. want to populate this from first & last name 
    public  string FullName { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

and a mapping file that looks like

```
     public ManagerMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.ManagerID);

        // Table & Column Mappings
        this.ToTable("Manager");
        this.Property(t => t.ManagerID).HasColumnName("ManagerID");

        this.Property(t => t.FirstName).HasColumnName("FirstName");
        this.Property(t => t.LastName).HasColumnName("LastName");
        this.Property(t => t.Email).HasColumnName("Email");
        this.Property(t => t.FullName).WhatToDo..? //<-- Can I / how does this mapping look

    }
}
```

Is it possible to create the `FullName` mapping or am I going about this the entirely wrong way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it is not possible to create `FullName` mapping. But you can use this simple workaround:

```
public class Manager
{
    public Manager(){}

    public int ManagerID { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public string FullName 
    { 
       get
       {
           return FirstName + " " + LastName;
       }
    }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

The only disadvantage of this approach is that you cannot use `FullName` property in linq-to-entities query (so you cannot for example order or search by `FullName` - you must still use `FirstName` and `LastName`).

If you use code generation feature of new Power Tools you should really declare this property in separate partial class as proposed by @Steve Mallory - don't modify generated code if you ever want to regenerate it.

Comment: You can still filter by it, as long as the entity collection is in memory, correct?

Comment: Yes you can filter by it when using linq to objects

Comment: Thanks.  embarrassed i asked.  forest from the trees issue on my end.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't map the field in the database. Instead, I would declare my POCO as partial. In another file, I would have the same partial class and define the combination value there (with only a getter). I have sample code if you need it.

Keeping it in a separate file helps if you do any code generation later.

Comment: Can you post an example of this in action? Would be useful for others