# Entity Framework, not mapped property in query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext

I'm creating an entity model in which I want to put a not mapped properties. These properties are there to simplify access to values from relationship. Model shown is just a simple example.
[image: Example model]

In users_roles entity, named `UserRole`, I want to have `UserName` property and `RoleName`.

```
public class UserRole 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int IdUser { get; set; }
    public int IdRole { get; set; }

    public User User { get; set; }
    public Role Role { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public string UserName
    {
        get { return User.Name; }
    }
    [NotMapped]
    public string RoleName
    {
        get { return Role.Name; }
    }
}
```

It's important for me for future filtering, databinding, etc. I do not insist on such a solution. It's just a first idea.

For now, if I try to filter entities by `UserName` or `RoleName` I have an exception, because `NotMapped` properties don't exist in the database.

Second thing is getting a value of properties after `DbContext` dispose. For now I'm using `.Include()` method (Eager Loading), but is it possible to get both above functionality (filterint, etc. and eager loading values) in one way?

**Edit 1:**
I'm using `Code First` strategy of model creation.
**Edit 2:**
Ok, to clarify, the most basic answer is to create a filter method like that

```
public IQueryable<UserRole> Filter(IQueryable<UserRole> query, string userName, string roleName)
{
    return query.Where(x => x.User.Name.Contains(userName) && x.Role.Name.Contains(roleName));
}
```

Comment: did you added these properties through designer!!! you must add it manually in the class not in the designer.desginer expects database mapping/modelling for the things  it shows.

Comment: No, it's `Code First` strategy, so I have no designer. I forgot to write.

Comment: the filtering won't work with Linq-to-entities but certainly using linq to Objects, check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6065201/entity-framework-4-1-code-first-mapping-populating-a-single-property-from-two-db

Answer (score 1):

Basically, if you will do something like

```
Context.UserRole.Where(x=>x.UserName == "login")
```

you will have an exception, as you discribed. You can achive this by using

```
Context.UserRole.Include(x=>x.User).Where(x=>x.User.Name == "login")
```

Comment: OK, that's the way I used till now. Basically, the example above is really simple and of course Your answer is great for it, but when I have to merge strings from 2 related entities and check if one of them exist every time I want to get the value, than it's problematic. Maybe there is no other solution :) To clarify `Context.UserRole.Where(x => (x.User != null ? x.User.Name + " " : "") + x.Role.Name == "sth")`. There could be more complex queries.

Comment: Can not understand why do you need to do filtering like this. You are summing "Dogs" and "Ducks". Better solution will be like: Context.UserRole.Where(x=>x.User.Name == /null or something/).Where(x=>x.Role.Name == "sth")

Comment: Maybe that will be a better example (but with no null check). `Context.User.Where(x => x.FirstName + " " + x.LastName == "FullName")`. This full name is a value from one textbox.

Comment: Kind of this. But there are possible issues - SQL indicies will not work for this query. And if the table became a big - you will have a bad performance. Better would be to split FullName onto two parts and compare FirstName and LastName to both of these parts.

Comment: Also, you can store FirstName and LastName as FullName in table. Or you could add a persistent calculated column into table with FirstName and LastName

Comment: OK, I have to think about this performance issue and maybe I split query to 2 independent columns. Back to the topic - the answer is there is no posibility to filter some related column as `NotMapped` property. The correct way, in this case, is to create a method f.ex. type of `IQueryable<UserRole>` with same type of argument and build query without additional properties, but only with persistent columns from DB.